# PHP foreach in English

Tags: php, foreach, semantics

This may sound weird but since not an English native, I'm having a trouble grasping the semantics of 'as' in the code.

> $array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);{
>   foreach ($array **as** &$value) 
>   $value = $value * 2;}

I don't get the meaning of as. I get what the command line is producing, but it's confusing for me probably as some of this would be for you:

> foreach ($array with &$value) 
>   or
>
> foreach ($array then &$value)

Can some native Englishman/lady explain me why was 'as' chosen for this purpose.

Comment: You know what the command line is producing.. so how would you explain that?

Comment: for each array item identified as value...

Comment: You have a bucket of chocolates and u have given a name called chocobucket , you can say foreach(chocobucket as chocolates ) here chocobucket  refers your chocolate collection and chocolates refers to  each chocolates in the bucket. So in array its same !!

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: `foreach(chocobucket as chocolate)`, not `chocolates`. You can't eat each ***chocolates*** in a bucket :-)

Answer (score 10):

It means something like
`foreach item in $array provide it to me as variable $value`

Answer (score 2):

Just look it up in the [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as#Adverb):

> In the manner or role specified.
>
> The kidnappers released him as agreed.   The parties were seen as agreeing on a range of issues.   He was never seen as the boss, but rather as a friend.

So in the context of `foreach` it means: go through every element of the array and use it **as** the specified variable (`foreach($array as $content)`).

Comment: The quoted text is not actually related to the original question that was asked.

Comment: @AmalMurali It is, as it explains one of the meanings of **as** as an adverb.

Comment: It does explain the meaning of **as** and provides some examples, but that's not actually relevant to the question, IMHO. +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

For example, if there are 3 items in `$array` with numeric index, then the `as` means each time through the loop `$value` equals the current item, so you can think of it as an **alias** for the current item:

```
//first iteration
$value = $array[0]
//second
$value = $array[1]
//third
$value = $array[2]
```

It is the same as:

```
for($key=0; $key<count($array); $key++) {
    $value = $array[$key];
}

foreach($array as $key => $value) { }
```

Comment: Thanx, that was nice. I still can't give a 'vote up' so I had to disregard the forum advice not to put out a simple 'thanks comment' but yours and GhostGambler's answer, really put it well in my head after couple of minutes of thinking.